# Does ag-grid supports column virtualization?

Tags: ag-grid, virtualization

Its specially important in scenarios with lots of columns which most of them are not in viewable area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as stated on the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-accessibility/#dom-order),

> By default the grid uses virtualisation; a technique whereby the grid
>   draws columns and rows as the user scrolls.

However, if you wish to disable column virtualization, you may choose to set the `suppressColumnVirtualisation` input property as `true`. You may refer to the column/row properties over [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/#scrolling).

There may be 2 scenarios when you may wish to disable column virtualization.

1) [Auto-sizing](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#auto-size-columns) of all columns. This will ensure that all columns, and not just the columns which are rendered on the screen, will be resized.

2) Support for a11y. This is to prevent any potential issues for keyboard navigation and screen readers.

Comment: I don't think it does. If you look at api one has to declare all the columns to start with. For column virtualisation to work one has to be able to provide column definitions on demand and only for the active viewport not for the entire grid.